# Would it be OK to edit questions that are of the form "What do you call a person who..."

Tags: discussion

This question went hot on the network today:

[What is a word that means "someone who pretends to be your friend but is actually your enemy?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188604/what-do-you-call-someone-who-pretends-to-be-your-friend-but-is-actually-your-ene)

Upon visiting it, I found that there are lots of other questions like this.

This one, and the others, suffer from the problem that what is really being asked is "what is a word that means 'a person who...'?"

But the answers are full of words that don't mean that at all, they are simply "names" that could be applied to a person like that.

For example, none of these words, offered as answers, mean "a person who pretends to be your friend but is your enemy":

a'hole
d'bag
sociopath
deceitful
con artist
traitor
disloyal
perfidious

So I'm wondering if it is a legitimate edit, to change questions of this nature to "What is a word for a that means a person who... ?"

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable idea to me. I don't know if your rep allows you to unilaterally apply such an edit, but if not presumably you can *propose* one. If you'd done that last week, say, and I'd been prompted to approve or reject it (my higher rep means things like that show up in my "review queue"), I might previously have been tempted to reject it as "Too Minor". But you've made a good point here, so if I see any such proposed edits in future I for one will ***accept*** them.

Comment: (Personally, I'd standardise on plain *"Word meaning a person who..."* - but as you imply, there are many alternative phrasings which are much better than *"What do you call a person who..."*)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you won't change it to "What is a word for a that means a person who... ?" because that's not comprehensible. But in general, I think changing "word for a person who..." to "word that describes a person who..." (for instance) doesn't substantially change the intent of the question and could be a valid clarifying edit.

Comment: I don't think OP was suggesting changing *"word for a person who..."* to *"word that describes a person who..."*. Unless I misunderstood, the specific issue was *"What do you call [such a person]?"* - which could easily be interpreted as *"How do you address [him]?"*. That interpretation is more likely to encourage (imho, worthless) answers like *"Asshole"*, which we'd like to discourage.

Comment: That would still be a clarifying edit, most likely, and so it would still be valid.

Comment: Indeed. Though per my original comment, until OP here explained *why* such an edit might be considered "clarifying", I'd have been tempted to see it as "too minor". Personally, I don't rate the built-in site search facilities here very highly, but I *do* think standardising on common question types (such as "word1 vs word2", "word meaning xxx", etc.) would slightly improve matters. And that's an additional justification - separate from the "clarifying" one.